# When should I use or not BooleanUtils.isTrue(...) and BooleanUtils.isFalse(...)?

Tags: java, programming-practices, apache

About this function: [`org.apache.commons.lang3.BooleanUtils.isFalse(Boolean bool)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html#isFalse%28java.lang.Boolean%29) and the similar `isTrue`, my co-work (less experienced) use it for **every** boolean in the code. I am trying to convince him that it is not a good practice because make the code confusing. In my POV, it should be used ONLY if the boolean to be tested is a type of non-primitive `Boolean` and it can be `null`. Actually, even this I think it is unnecessary, because the implementation of this function is simply `Boolean.TRUE.equals(bool)` or `Boolean.FALSE.equals(bool)`. Anyway, I think it is totally crazy do something like:

```
boolean isReady = true;

if (BooleanUtils.isTrue(isReady)) {
   // ...
}
```

when you cold simply do

```
if (isReady) {
   // ...
}
```

or `(!isReady)` for the opposite.

His only argument to use this is "it is easy to read". I just can't accept this argument. Am I wrong? What arguments can I use to convince him that no useless code is better than useless code in this case?

Thank you guys.

Comment: `BooleanUtils.isTrue(isReady)` is really hard to read for me because it is tooooooo looooong.

Comment: For the record: I agree with you completely. These methods are totally useless, since they are exactly as long as the implementation and no more clear in meaning.

Comment: Never. Also, in my experience, apache apis are very often badly designed.

Comment: this is only useful when you use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`, cause then there are 3 different possible values: true, false and null. When null, a NullPointerException will be thrown. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479806/boolean-object-and-boolean-variable-issue-in-java

Comment: @Salvatorelab: you forgot FILE_NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's absurd to use `BooleanUtils.isTrue(isReady)` when `isReady` is a `boolean`, not a `Boolean`.  Your colleague seems like one of those guys who thinks that the more code he writes, the more productive he is.  Maybe he should go find a job programming in Ada.

Comment: Or maybe they pay him per line.

Comment: I rather suspect that the colleage is simply a pretentious noob. He probably read or heard once, somewhere, that using "BooleanUtils.isTrue" makes a code better. He either did not understand the explanation behind it, or he forgot it soon afterwards. But he is happy to remember *a rule*, and now he applies it dogmatically. Give him enough time, and he will learn hundreds of other rules. (Never use "==", always use "equals". Never make subclasses, always encapsulate. Every class must have an interface. Always use design patterns, the more the better. Always/Never use synchronized methods. Etc.)

Comment: sometimes this slavish rule adherence turns into mass hysteria, e.g. the Java style rule that constants should be all upper case, carried over from C, where it was a work-around for the use of `#define` to define constants.

Answer (score 2):

1) Bugs come from code. The more code you have, the more bugs. Always try to write less code, even if that's just a few words here and there.

2) Easy isn't Easiest. Which is *easiest* to read?

Try compromising with `if(isReady == True)`, if he really wants that explicit comparison.

Comment: `if (isReady == True)` ??  When does it end? Why not `if ((isReady == True) == True)` ?

Comment: @kevincline: I'd use `if(isReady == True)` in a language that implicitly casts non-boolean values to booleans in if conditions, as it improves the type-safety of the underlying language: `if(0 == true)` ought to result in a compilation warning.

Comment: @kevincline I'm trying to figure out /why/ the op's antagonist wants that syntax, and the best I can come up with is he wants to see that you're checking against True.

Answer (score 1):

I think the goal should be to have descriptive boolean variable names, as you have shown in your example.

Comment: I thought exactly the same thing today rethinking about this. Using descriptive boolean kills his argument of "it is easy to read". The above answer also makes a good point: if he find "isReady == true" ugly, so there is no reason to think BooleanUtils.isTrue(isReady) beautiful. Tomorrow I'll try theses arguments.

Comment: @FelipeMicaroniLalli good luck!